# Is a coordinate patch a diffeomorphism on its image?

Tags: real-analysis, manifolds

A coordinate patch on a manifold $M$ is defined as a map $\alpha:U\to V$, where $U$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^k$ and $V$ is open in $M$, such that: $\alpha$ is a homomorphism of class $C^r$ with $r\ge1$ whose derivative $D_x\alpha$ is an injection for each $x\in U$. I'm wondering, do these conditions imply that $\alpha$ is a diffeomorphism? If not, can you give a counter-example?

Comment: The answer is essentially yes. But note that you can’t even define what a diffeomorphism is without using coordinate patches.

Comment: Isn't a diffeomorphism just a differentiable invertible function with differentiable derivative? Why are coordinate patches needed to define it?

Comment: What's the definition of a differentiable map from a manifold to another manifold?